# How to export a mesh with armature and actions to a fbx

Tags: animation, armature, export, .fbx, actions

Im having some troubles exporting my character to an fbx.

I have a character humanoid and a custom rig for that, that has DEF bones and targets / controllers.

I animated all the targets and controllers and they follow the def so I get the animation in blender.

The problem is when I try to export it. If I export as it is it gets exported with weird bones rotation (for example a leg flipped). I tried baking too, but the animation isnt the same (for example a bone wont move). Also I tried messing with the fbx export setting but nothing. Any clue?

This happens importing it in Unity and in Blender again.

I add the .blend file too:

https://we.tl/t-924AyVEkdZ